# Justifying holomorphicity of a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to a Banach space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm looking to show that if $X$ is a Banach space and $T : X\to X$ is a bounded linear map $f : \mathbb{C}\to X$ given by $f(z) = \exp(zT)$ is holomorphic. In other words the following limit exists
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z-z_0}
$$
Here's what I have so far:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z-z_0} & = \lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n - z_0^n}{z-z_0}\frac{T^n}{n!} \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z^n - z_0^n}{z - z_0}\frac{T^n}{n!} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z_0^{n-1}\frac{T^n}{(n-1)!} \\
& = Tf(z)
\end{aligned}
$$
This is the expected result, the only issue I'm having is justifying the jump from the second line to the third line. How can I pull the limit inside the sum?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough explanation:

We have 
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{z^{n}-z_{0}^{n}}{z-z_{0}}\right|&=|z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}z_{0}+\cdots+z_{0}^{n-1}|\\
&\leq(|z_{0}|+1)^{n-1}+(|z_{0}|+1)^{n-2}|z_{0}|+\cdots+|z_{0}|^{n-1}\\
&\leq n(|z_{0}|+1)^{n-1},
\end{align*}
for $z$ sufficiently closed to $z$, and 
\begin{align*}
\left\|\dfrac{z^{n}-z_{0}^{n}}{z-z_{0}}\dfrac{T^{n}}{n!}\right\|\leq\dfrac{((|z_{0}|+1)\|T\|)^{n}}{(n-1)!},
\end{align*}
and the series of the form 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 2}\dfrac{a^{n}}{(n-1)!}
\end{align*}
converges for $a\geq 0$.

So we are allowed to use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, but in Bochner integrals sense, such that we can swipe the limit with the infinite sum.